# asp mvc 2 with jquery jtable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-jtable

I´m trying to make things work with jTable but the listaction is not firing the POST action in the Controller...

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#gridviewField').jtable({
    title: 'The User List',
    actions: {
        listAction: '/Customer/UserList'
    },
    fields: {
        Id: {
            key: true,
            create: false,
            edit: false,
            list: false
        },
        customerId: {
            title: 'Customer Id',
            list: false
        },
        Name: {
            title: 'Name',
            width: '15%'
        },
        Username: {
            title: 'Username',
            width: '15%'
        },
        EmailAddress: {
            title: 'Email address',
            width: '15%'
        }
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
<HttpPost()> _
        Public Function UserList() As JsonResult
            Try
                Dim users = _model.Users
                Return Json(New With {.Result = "OK", .Records = users})
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return Json(New With {.Result = "ERROR", .Message = ex.Message})
            End Try
        End Function
```

Does jTable work with MVC 2? It should be working like this..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had to put the script code in the aspx file. It's working now.